# Pytest/Hypothesis not matching string as expected

Tags: python, floating-point, pytest, sanic, python-hypothesis

I am testing a validate function I am using with Sanic.

```
def validate(val):
    try:
        if isinstance(val, bool):  # Here because the int(val) line will success with int(True)/int(False)
            raise ValueError()
        if isinstance(val, float):
            print("IT'S FLOAT!")
            raise ValueError()
        if '.' in str(val):
            raise ValueError()
        n = int(val)
    except ValueError as ex:
        raise InvalidUsage('Invalid value "{}" for int param "n"'.format(val))
```

I'm testing this against float values and using Hypothesis to generate the test conditions.

```
@given(val=st.floats())
def test_validate_int_float(val):
    with pytest.raises(InvalidUsage) as ex:
        validate(val)
    print("{}|{}|{}".format(ex.value, f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"',
                            ex.value == f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"'))
    assert ex.match(f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"')
```

This test fails:

```
Falsifying example: test_validate_int_float(val=1e+16)
```

The print statement looks like this:

```
IT'S FLOAT!
Invalid value "1e+16" for int param "n"|Invalid value "1e+16" for int param "n"|False
```

Why is my assert not matching? The strings look the same to me. I am assuming it's due to the float value, but in that case, how do I properly match the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `ex.value` to str prior to checking equality with:

```
print("{}|{}|{}".format(ex.value, f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"',
                        str(ex.value) == f'Invalid value "{val}" for int param "n"'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about `str()`. However, I don't think the comment about not hitting the ValueError is correct. I've updated my post to show the print statement I added in (without the `str()` fix to keep your answer valid). It's printing the statement as expected.

Comment: Yep, I was wrong about that part and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What version of pytest and of Python?  I'm pretty sure this is a pytest usage issue, not anything to do with Hypothesis.

While not an answer, using the `match` *argument* to `pytest.raises` rather than the method on the thing it returns is often easier to read, and I suspect would not have the same issue.

Comment: Hypothesis - 4.36.2, Pytest - 5.1.3